# Doctor(.....) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(.....)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating form which accepts nested attributes:
    #doctor.rb

```
#user.rb
  has_one :doctor
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :doctor, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['cartridge_name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

my strong parameters:

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,:birthday, :address, :phone,:email, :role, :social => [],
                    :doctor => [:position,:department_id,:salary_type,:date_came,:monthly_salary,:percentage_salary,:id],
end
```

But i got error:

```
Doctor(#70193541488440) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70193536484960)
```

Probably it is the problem with associations or with my strong params.

EDIT:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url:create_doctor_users_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for @doctor do |u| %>
          <%= render 'doctor_attributes', f:u %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT2:

```
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"birXhqxdplQMfZF5G8jDM9wi1nsBwkJfWsHcE8ZbPCxxemgR8ObmCFzODqoHAcTDo9jNMN0G0HK69A4hGy0Ddg==", 
"user"=>{"name"=>"", "birthday"=>"", "address"=>"", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"", 
"doctor"=>{"position"=>"", "department_id"=>"", "salary_type"=>"Зарплата", "date_came"=>"", "monthly_salary"=>"", "percentage_salary"=>""}, 
"educations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"from"=>"", "to"=>"", "institution"=>"", "major"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, 
"job_experiences_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"from"=>"", "to"=>"", "institution"=>"", "position"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Зарегестрировать"}
```

And also I think this is important, i am doing creation in controller this way:

```
@user = User.new
@doctor = Doctor.new
@user.job_experiences.build
@user.educations.build
```

I guess i should do:

```
@user.doctor.build
```

as with job_experiences, but i get error:

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `user_params` to this:

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,:birthday, :address, :phone,:email, :role, :social => [],
                    :doctor_attributes => [:position,:department_id,:salary_type,:date_came,:monthly_salary,:percentage_salary,:id]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
end
```

Explain:
If you are using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) in the model, you should pass the `permitted` params as `doctor_attributes` not `doctor`, under the hood rails create an object `Doctor` as it described in your errors.

Read a wonderful article about [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms/).

### Update:

Fix your form to:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :doctor, @user.build_doctor do |u| %>
       <%= render 'doctor_attributes', f:u %>
  <% end %>
```

when in your parameters you should see:

```
"doctor_attributes"=>{" ....}
```

instead of:

```
"doctor"=>{" ....}
```

Comment: @Зеленый, I get an error: Unpermitted parameter: doctor

Comment: @yerassyl post your form please, you should use `fields_for` according `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, as in article about `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: @yerassyl ok, now please post a piece of log where i can see request with parametrs.

Comment: and just for tips if you are using `has_one` then build a doctor object looks like `@user.build_doctor` if `has_many`  then `@user.doctors.build`